# Error C2146 for win32 project

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, mfc

```
void CMainWindow::OnPaint ()
{
    CPaintDC dc (this);

    CRect rect;
    GetClientRect (&rect);

    dc.DrawText (_T ("Hello, MFC"), -1, &rect,DT_SINGLELINE ¦ DT_CENTER ¦ DT_VCENTER);
}
```

I am not able to find out what goes wrong in the above simple code .
Whenever i compile my code , it gives me the following error :

```
1>c:\users\e543925.pacrim1\desktop\vc++\test\test\test.cpp(38) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ')' before identifier '¦'
1>c:\users\e543925.pacrim1\desktop\vc++\test\test\test.cpp(38) : error C2059: syntax error : ')'
```

Please help ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`¦` is not the same character as `|`. You need `|`.

Answer (score 1):

didn't you mean `|`  not `¦` ? This is difference.
Change it to:

```
dc.DrawText (_T ("Hello, MFC"), -1, &rect,DT_SINGLELINE | DT_CENTER | DT_VCENTER);
```